# Melodyne nightmare

Tags: pro-tools, daw, editing, vocals

Does anyone else started noticing weird "sampling" noises on Melodyne over last updates of RTAS version (running old - aka before DNA Melodyne - last updated and Protools 8 or 9). Problem is on both and on several projects!

I feel like i could kill someone I'll have to go take out the silence on every track and slide in the original breathing this is days worth of work!

Please tell me that someone out there saw this and that an update fixed it? I'm even willing to pay for DNA update!!!

Comment: What sample rate are your audio files?

Comment: ahh, yes... both 44.1k and 48khz. One is a indie band project that I didn't dream having to be doing this kind of editing and the other is a more serious project where I knew extensive amounts of beat detective, elastic audio and melodyne would be in order.

Comment: Usually these noises are caused by Melodyne operating at a different sample rate than the audio files it's processing.  If that's not the case, you might want to post on [their forums](http://www.celemony.com/userforum/viewforum.php?f=13) and report back.